# How can I use where with two condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 columns:

1. `CategoryID`
2. `Name`

How can I use `where` if name only in a CategoryID = 1 and has a NULL value it will not show.

```
where not (name IS NULL or categoryID = 1)
```

I tried this but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you indicated that records should not be displayed when "name *only* in a CategoryID = 1 *and* has a NULL value", try this:

```
WHERE CategoryID <> 1 OR
      (CategoryID = 1 AND Name IS NOT NULL)
```

This will display records with any `CategoryID`, just not records where `CategoryID = 1` *and* `Name IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking where name is not null and the categoryID is 1 then this will work.

where (**NOT** name IS NULL **AND** categoryID = 1)

Comment: Sorry that is NOT name is null

Comment: Or, I prefer ((NOT name IS NULL)AND(categoryID=1)) for readability:)

Answer (score 0):

I combined both of your suggestion and It's work !

```
  WHERE ((t.STDName Is not Null)OR( t.ID != 1))
```

like this Thank you very much